# SecurityConfig is breaking OAuth2 in Spring Boot 1.5

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement OAuth2 to a web application that runs on Spring Boot 1.5. I am using KeyCloak as my OAuth2 server.

I have done the following:

- Updated `application.properties` with the required `security.oauth2.client.*` and `security.oauth2.resource.*` properties
- Added the oauth2 dependency to my `pom.xml`
- Added `@EnableOAuth2Sso` to the class that contains my `main` method
- Deleted my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class (more about this below)

With this setup, the login process works as expected. i.e.

- Visit my application's homepage
- Get redirected to KeyCloak to login
- Get redirected to the application after a successful login.

But, when I add a class that implements `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (I am also using the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` and `@Configuration` class annotations, Spring Boot seems to completely ignore OAuth2 and instead of a login page, i just get "Access Denied"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

### Oauth2 Authentication with an old version of spring (spring version < 2.7)

If you just enable the oauth2 dependency and set the properties, then spring will do what you logically expect it to do. On the other hand, if you explicitly ask to use your own configuration, which is what you do when you add a class implementing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, then it's up to you to specify that you want to use oauth 2.

To do this, you can inject an HttpSecurity bean and override configure methodlike this:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .oauth2Login()
            .authorizationEndpoint()
                ...
            .redirectionEndpoint()
                ...
            .tokenEndpoint()
                ...
            .userInfoEndpoint()
                ...
}
```

[Full code sample in spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2login-advanced.html)

However, I recommend that you use at least Spring 2.7.0, which uses the new Spring Security architecture with the new notion of security filter chain it’s really easier.

Comment: Hi, the ```oauth2Login()``` method is not available in Spring Boot 1.5 (I was able to get this working in another Spring Boot 2 application using this method, though). I would like to try and get this working in Spring Boot 1.5 for now (but I know that I will soon have to upgrade this application to Spring Boot 2 or 3 for security and convenience)

Comment: Yes sorry I updated the code sample for your version but I sincerely recommend to you to upgrade your spring version it’s really much easier